# Using NOT LIKE for multiple mutiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to search for particular value in multiple columns. Is there any way to optimize this query?

```
SELECT TOP (200) Events.EventDate, AVDCAV.CAVCH1, AVDCAV.CAVCH2, AVDCAV.CAVCH3, AVDCAV.CAVCH4, AVDCAV.CAVCH5, AVDCAV.CAVCH6, AVDCAV.CAVCH7, AVDCAV.CAVCH8, AVDCAV.CAVCH9
FROM AVDCAV
   INNER JOIN Events ON AVDCAV.IDEvent=Events.EventID
WHERE CAVCH9 NOT LIKE '0.0000000000' OR CAVCH8 NOT LIKE '0.0000000000' OR CAVCH7 NOT LIKE '0.0000000000' OR CAVCH1 NOT LIKE '0.0000000000'
ORDER BY AVDCAV.IDEvent DESC
```

I'm getting the data from SQL Express 2008 R2.

Comment: Seems like you're suffering of a bad table design. Why all those cavch columns?

Comment: I'm not the creator of the design

Comment: Poor you. Create a view that returns a normalized result. Then use that view instead.

Comment: Why are you using `LIKE` you're not searching with Wildcards.  Replace them with `CAVCH9 <> '0.0000000000'`

Comment: My answer was more for  readability, If you have performance issues then. Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Answer (score 3):

Because you aren't using any wildcard you don't need `LIKE`.

```
WHERE '0.0000000000' NOT IN  (CAVCH1, CAVCH7, CAVCH8, CAVCH9)
```

Btw the performance is the same, but easier to read.

Comment: No performance improvement. Gets translated into the same thing.

Comment: Optimize can mean a lot of things, also optimizing readability.

Comment: Ok this is good. But for my case its not suitable. There is no result after this query.

Comment: Well I didnt put enogh 0 , maybe was that?

Comment: No. For example if i use only the first two columns. I see results. In my question the query is running good(with the same 0s :P ).

Comment: So your code is equivalent to 'AND' in my case i want to use 'OR' :) Any idea?

Comment: Not relevant to your problem but why you store numeric values as strings?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing table sizes, current indices etc, you could try adding this index

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_AVDCAV ON AVDCAV ( IDEvent ) 
INCLUDE ( CAVCH1, CAVCH2, CAVCH3, CAVCH4, CAVCH5, CAVCH6, CAVCH7, CAVCH8, CAVCH9 )
```

to see if performance improves